# Alternate row color based on previous row/field's value / Improve existing solution

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-style

**EDIT 2 (ANSWER):** For anyone who runs across this looking for a solution to a similar problem, the solution is in the comments under Gianmarco's answer. The `productusage` array is pre-processed with the same function as the `$scope.alternate` function below, and the result used to set a isAlternate flag on each item in the array. That is then used in either an ng-style or ng-class attribute to determine which styling to use on the row.

**EDIT:** For clarity: I have groups of RANames where it might go... RAFoo, RAFoo, RABar, RABar, RABar, RABar, RABaz, RABaz, RABaz etc...and I don't want the row to alternate colors until it hits a new RAName. **There is a variable number of RAName values with the same RAName, so there could be 2 "RAFoo", 4 "RABar" and 3 "RABaz", etc.. and it can change up.**

I have the following code in my controller:

```
var prevRAName = ""; // intialize prevRAName to empty string
var switchColor = false; 

...

$scope.alternate = function (currRAName) {
        if (prevRAName) { // starts on 2nd row...
            if (currRAName == prevRAName) {
                prevRAName = currRAName;
            } else {
                switchColor = !switchColor;
                prevRAName = currRAName;
            }

        } else {
            prevRAName = currRAName;  // hits on the first row ...
        }

        return switchColor;
    }
```

And in the template I have:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in productusage | orderBy : ['RAName','PeriodStart']">
    <td ng-style="alternate(item.RAName)  ? {'background-color':'#f5f5f5'} : {'background-color':'white'}">{{item.RAName}}</td>
    <td ng-style="alternate(item.RAName)  ? {'background-color':'#f5f5f5'} : {'background-color':'white'}">{{item.ProductDescription}}</td>
    <td ng-style="{'background-color': '#' + intToRGB(hashCode(item.PeriodStart)), 'color' : 'white'}">{{item.PeriodCaseCt}}</td>
    <td ng-style="{'background-color': '#' + intToRGB(hashCode(item.PeriodStart)), 'color' : 'white'}">{{item.PeriodStart | date : format : shortDate}}</td>
</tr>
```

I am wanting to alternate the color of the RAName and ProductDescription fields of the table, effectively "grouping" them based on the RAName.  The PeriodCaseCt and PeriodCaseCt fields are color coded.  Now everything works as is and I wish that this was the end of the story, however I am getting a bunch of these errors:

`Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"alternate(item.RAName)  ? {'background-color':'#f5f5f5'} : {'background-color':'white'}","newVal":{"background-color":"white"},"oldVal":{"background-color":"#f5f5f5"}}`

Now, I don't need these values to be watched after the first pass, and it does correctly set everything and the end user would never know unless they had the developer tools/console tab open, but I know and its bugging the $#%% out of me. How can I improve/fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-class-odd and ng-class-even for odd and even elements in a ng-repeat cycle.

```
<ol>
  <li ng-repeat="obj in objects">
   <span ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
     {{obj}}
   </span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

The first and all the odds will have the 'odd' class while the even will have the 'even' class.

Inside each class you can insert whatever you want as attribute.

In your case you can to something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in productusage | orderBy : ['RAName','PeriodStart']" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
    <td>{{item.RAName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ProductDescription}}</td>
    <td ng-style="{'background-color': '#' + intToRGB(hashCode(item.PeriodStart)), 'color' : 'white'}">{{item.PeriodCaseCt}}</td>
    <td ng-style="{'background-color': '#' + intToRGB(hashCode(item.PeriodStart)), 'color' : 'white'}">{{item.PeriodStart | date : format : shortDate}}</td>
</tr>
```

and the CSS would be:

```
.odd td{background-color:#f5f5f5}
.even td{background-color:white}
```

If you want instead to reach a different result please explain better what you want (maybe with a working example) and I will change my answer

Comment: Unfortunately it is not that simple, I have groups of RANames where it might go... RAFoo, RAFoo, RABar, RABar, RABar, RABar, RABaz, RABaz, etc...and I don't want the row to alternate colors until it hits a new RAName.

Comment: then you can preprocess your productusage array and set a flag "alternate" to true or false. In the ng-repeat you will then call for each item a ng-class="alternative-class : alternate".

Comment: Pre-processing using the same code previously used in the $scope.alternate function and using the result to set a flag on each item in the productusage array worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on the coloring issue, you have a few options.  `ng-repeat` exposes an  `$index` which will give you the current index of the item you're iterating upon.  This is useful since you can pass it to a function on your scope, or use it directly.

```
  <div ng-repeat="thing in things track by $index">
    <div ng-style="{ 'color': $index % 2 ? 'red' : 'blue' }">{{ thing }}</div>
  </div>
```

Or, like I said, you can use a function on the scope and pass the index to it, like so:

```
  $scope.colorAlternate = function(index) {
    var color1 = 'red'
    var color2 = 'blue'
    return (index % 2) ? color1 : color2;
  }
```

Then access it in your `ng-style`.  You can also use `ng-class` for this if you want to swap out more than just a color.

```
  <div ng-repeat="thing in things track by $index">
    <div ng-style="{ 'color': colorAlternate($index) }">{{ thing }}</div>
  </div>
```

Edit: Adding a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) to the modulo operator in case you are unfamiliar with it.

Comment: I believe `$index` property is available in `ng-repeat` even if you don't `track by $index`, no?

Comment: Yep.  Not sure why I misremembered that. Editing to reflect that, thanks!

Comment: There is also an `$odd` and `$even` available in `ng-repeat`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Oh, nice!  I never knew that.  I suppose alternating is a common enough problem to add in helpers like that.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not as simple as $odd and $even... I edited the question for clarity..

Answer (score -1):

I am not eligible to comment that's why I have to write this answer.

The solution given is that one can use a flag to display the rows. Everything works fine with the flag added to the table data. But the problem occurs when a user sorts the table on the GUI and table is reordered.